# What does "Object obj: ArrayList" do in java?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have been looking at a friends java code and this came up. But im not sure what it is. Can anyone help quickly.
The code is like this:

```
for(Customers cust: customerArrayList) {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- fragment which I don't understand
```

Comment: I down voted because [Unclear what you're asking](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion)

Comment: Does it look something like `for (SomeElement oneElement : manyElements){..}`? If yes research "enhanced for loop". If no use [edit] option and provide more context (like fragment of code which contains what you are asking about).

Comment: Possibly related: [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/85190)

Comment: @Pshemo thanks a lot. i guess i got idea of it. Your comment helped

Comment: Why don't you just ask your friend.

Comment: Related: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html (relevant fragment starts with "The for statement also has another form ...")

Comment: Also very nice resource: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to following code :-

```
for(int i =0;i< customerArrayList.size();i++){
System.out.print(customerArrayList.get(i));
}
```